# How to get xml data with jsp page

Tags: java, xml, jsp

Need to show xml response with jsp page. I am getting Object of xml object"vehicleOrderResponse", If I will show this object in new file then xml is showing successfully, but not getting xml data in jsp page. Provide any piece of code to show xml response in jsp page?

Jsp page code:

```
try
        {
            SAMSServiceAdaptor serviceadaptor = new SAMSServiceAdaptor();
            VehicleOrderDetailRequestType vehicleOrderDetailRequest = serviceadaptor.createRequest(
                    vin, bodyCode, dealerCode, ordernumber, modelYear);
            vehicleOrderResponse = SAMSServiceLocator.getSAMSServicePort().retrieveVehicleOrderDetail(vehicleOrderDetailRequest);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                        .newInstance(VehicleOrderDetailResponseType.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                        true);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            marshaller.marshal(vehicleOrderResponse, bytes);
            String sb = new String(bytes.toByteArray());
            String responseXML = sb.trim();
            if(responseXML!=null){
                out.println(responseXML.trim().substring("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".length()));    
            }else{
                    out.println("Response was null, Please check input paramters! ");
                }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            out.println(ex.toString());
        }
```

Xml response in file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:VehicleOrderType xmlns="urn:ford/interface/VehicleOrder/UnitDetail/v2" xmlns:ns2="urn:ford/VehicleOrder/UnitDetail/v2.0">
    <VehicleOrder>
        <ModelYear>2014</ModelYear>
        <Dealer>13058</Dealer>
        <Body>P8J</Body>
        <ItemNo>445S  </ItemNo>
        <Vin>1ZVBP8JZ3E5223527</Vin>
        <Division>F                             </Division>
        <GsdbSiteCode>G9W1A</GsdbSiteCode>
        <CurrentBuildWeek>2013-04-01Z</CurrentBuildWeek>
        <ReceiptDate>2013-03-07Z</ReceiptDate>
        <VehicleLineDescription>Mustang</VehicleLineDescription>
        <BodyDescription>P8J Coupe Shelby GT500</BodyDescription>
        <Status>
            <ns2:Status>Sold                          </ns2:Status>
            <ns2:StatusDateTime>2013-05-04T04:00:00.000Z</ns2:StatusDateTime>
        </Status>
    </VehicleOrder>
</ns2:VehicleOrderType>
```

Comment: Use JSTL instead of scriptlets in JSP

Comment: Rightclick JSP page in browser and do *View Source*. Look closer. It's there. It's just being literally interpreted as part of JSP's HTML output. However no one of the XML elements are valid HTML (like `<p>`, `<br>`, etc), so the browser ignores them during presentation. Perhaps you want to display the XML preformatted? Or perhaps you want to display the XML HTML-escaped?

Comment: Yes, found xml data in page source, but how Can I return xml data in jsp, any piece of code which can help me out? No need to display xml prefomatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your XML content pre-formatted by wrapping it within `<pre>` tags to prevent the browser from trying to interpret it as HTML and display it as is:

```
<pre>
    <%
      // your existing code
    %>
</pre>
```

A better option would be to move out your JSP scriptlet `<% %>` code into a Servlet that sets the XML content as a *request attribute* before forwarding the request to the JSP using a `RequestDispatcher`.

```
String responseXML = new String(bytes.toByteArray()).trim();
if (responseXML != null) {
    request.setAttribute("responseXML", responseXML.substring(
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>".length()));
}
```

Then, finally within your JSP use JSTL's `<c:out>` tag. This would escape the XML automatically for you.

```
<p>
    <c:out value="${responseXML}" />
</p>
```